# Need to help based on condition query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question about SQL Server

Table : `patient`

```
dos             |pn     |code   |servicecode
--------------------------------------------
2015-09-21      |10     |4      |90
2015-10-06      |10     |4      |91
2015-09-04      |10     |4      |92
2015-04-07      |11     |5      |94
2015-04-08      |11     |5      |94
2015-02-02      |12     |6      |96
2015-02-02      |12     |6      |97
2015-07-21      |12     |6      |94
2012-11-07      |13     |7      |94
2012-11-07      |13     |7      |99
2013-10-07      |13     |7      |90
2014-11-09      |13     |7      |98
2014-12-17      |13     |7      |90
```

Table 2: `Patientrefs`

```
Pn    |  code    | sdate      |  edate 
------------------------------------------
10    |   4      | 2015-09-04 | 2015-10-05
11    |   5      | 2015-04-01 | 2015-09-21
12    |   6      | 2015-02-02 | 2015-10-12
12    |   6      | 2014-04-20 | 2014-05-23
13    |   7      | 2012-11-05 | 2015-05-20
```

Table 3: `PatientService`

```
Servicecode
-----------
90
94
```

Here `patient` and `patientrefts` common columns Pn + code  if pn+ code combination matches then we look into min(dos) after that `patient` table `servicecode` look into `patientservice` table service code then that combination matches then we consider dos is minimumdos

Based on above tables I want output like below

```
pn    | code   | mindos
---------------------------
11    | 5      | 2015-04-07
13    | 7      | 2012-11-07
```

Here pn=10 and pn=12 do not have mindos because of min(dos) related service code not satisfy with patientservice table service code

I tried like this

```
 select
     pn, code, dos as mindos 
 from 
     (select 
          pn, code, servicecode 
      from
          (select    
               pn, code, servicecode,
               row_number() over (partition by pn, code order by dos) as rn
           from patient) a
      inner join   
           patientrefs b on a.pn = b.pn and a.code = b.code and b.rn = 1
                         and a.dos between b.sdate and b.edate) as mindos 
 inner join 
     patientservic c on mindos.servicecode = c.servicecode
```

But above query is not returning the expected result accurately.

Please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server

Comment: why is there no result for 10|4 and 12|6?

Comment: Patient 10 has a `ServiceCode` of 90.  The `PatientService` table includes a `ServiceCode` 90.  Should patient 10 appear in the results?

Comment: Patient
dos             |pn     |code   |servicecode
2015-09-21      |10     |4      |90
2015-10-06      |10     |4      |91
2015-09-04      |10     |4      |92
 Patientrefs
Pn    |  code    | sdate      |  edate 
10    |   4      | 2015-09-04 | 2015-10-05 here  patient table dos foll between sdate and edate of patientrefs table then we will consider min(dos) in patient table that time min(dos) is
2015-09-04      |10     |4      |92 then we look in patientservice table servicecode match with patien table servicecodethat time records is not match so pn=10 donot have mindos similar way pn:12

Comment: Here mainly we need to consider dos foll between sdate and edate.if satisfy then we go min(dos)in patient table then that records corresponding servicecode is match with patientservice table if not matche then there is no mindos of that patient.can you please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTEs you can perform the min(dos) and "in range" checks.  Then just join the CTE with the patient and PatientSevice tables to validate the code.  Below is the code to recreate your example dataset and the query to return your final dataset.  Enjoy!

```
    /* RECREATE THE DATASETS

    IF OBJECT_ID('patient') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE patient

    CREATE TABLE patient
    (
          dos  DATE
        , pn   INT
        , code INT
        , servicecode INT
    )

    INSERT patient
    VALUES ('2015-09-21', 10, 4, 90)
          ,('2015-10-06', 10, 4, 91)
          ,('2015-09-04', 10, 4, 92)
          ,('2015-04-07', 11, 5, 94)
          ,('2015-04-08', 11, 5, 94)
          ,('2015-02-02', 12, 6, 96)
          ,('2015-02-02', 12, 6, 97)
          ,('2015-07-21', 12, 6, 94)
          ,('2012-11-07', 13, 7, 94)
          ,('2012-11-07', 13, 7, 99)
          ,('2013-10-07', 13, 7, 90)
          ,('2014-11-09', 13, 7, 98)
          ,('2014-12-17', 13, 7, 90)

    IF OBJECT_ID('Patientrefs') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE Patientrefs

    CREATE TABLE Patientrefs
    (
          pn   INT
        , code INT
        , sdate DATE
        , edate DATE
    )

    INSERT Patientrefs
    VALUES (10, 4, '2015-09-04', '2015-10-05')
          ,(11, 5, '2015-04-01', '2015-09-21')
          ,(12, 6, '2015-02-02', '2015-10-12')
          ,(12, 6, '2014-04-20', '2014-05-23')
          ,(13, 7, '2012-11-05', '2015-05-20')

    IF OBJECT_ID('PatientService') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE PatientService

    CREATE TABLE PatientService
    (
          servicecode INT
    )

    INSERT PatientService
    VALUES (90),(94)

    */

    WITH CTEmindos AS -->>Get the min(dos)
    (
        SELECT pn, code, MIN(dos) mindos
        FROM patient
        GROUP BY pn, code
    ),
    CTEinrange AS  -->>eliminate min(dos) if it's not in range
    (
        SELECT c.pn, c.code, c.mindos
        FROM Patientrefs cpr
            JOIN CTEmindos c ON c.pn = cpr.pn AND c.code = cpr.code
        WHERE c.mindos BETWEEN cpr.sdate AND cpr.edate
    )
    -->>if the min(dos) is in range return only valid service code records
    SELECT ci.pn, ci.code, ci.mindos
    FROM patient p
        JOIN CTEinrange ci ON ci.pn = p.pn AND ci.code = p.code AND ci.mindos = p.dos
        JOIN PatientService ps ON ps.Servicecode = p.servicecode
```